# TypeError: Object of type filter is not JSON serializable - Nested Object

Tags: python, json

```
import csv
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
    
    decoded_file = csvFilePath.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
   
    #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file) 
    #convert each csv row into python dict
    for row in csvReader: 
        #add this python dict to json array
        option = [row['option1'], row['option2'], row['option3'], row['option4']]
        option = filter(None, option)
        newJson = {
          'numb': row['numb'],
          'question': row['question'],
          'answer': row['answer'],
          'options': option
        }
        jsonArray.append(newJson)

    print('>>>>>>>jsonArray>>>>>>>', jsonArray)

    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray)

    print('>>>>>>>jsonString>>>>>>>', jsonString)

    return jsonArray
```

Error

```
TypeError at /path/path
Object of type filter is not JSON serializable

>>>>>>>jsonArray>>>>>>> [{'numb': '1', 'question': 'What does HTML stand for?', 'answer': 'Hyper Text Markup Language', 'options': <filter object at 0x7f3d3459fa00>}, {'numb': '2', 'question': 'What does CSS stand for?', 'answer': 'Cascading Style Sheet', 'options': <filter object at 0x7f3d34317400>}]
```

If i comment out `# 'options': option` from `newJson` then it works perfectly

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: It should be ``'options': list(option)`` instead of ``'options': option``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, a filter object is not serializable.

But a list is

```
'options': list(option)
```

However, it's not really clear to me what you're filtering. A list with None types will become null in the JSON array

Comment: Oh, just a small change, It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

JSON does not know how to convert a `filter` object into a JSON string. In order to put `option` into the JSON string, you need to convert it to a list first:

```py
import csv
import json 

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
    
    decoded_file = csvFilePath.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
   
    # load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(decoded_file) 
    # convert each csv row into python dict
    for row in csvReader: 
        # add this python dict to json array
        option = [row['option1'], row['option2'], row['option3'], row['option4']]
        option = list(filter(None, option))
        newJson = {
          'numb': row['numb'],
          'question': row['question'],
          'answer': row['answer'],
          'options': option
        }
        jsonArray.append(newJson)

    print('>>>>>>>jsonArray>>>>>>>', jsonArray)

    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray)

    print('>>>>>>>jsonString>>>>>>>', jsonString)

    return jsonArray
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in function `filter()` has no default Encoder as per documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html.

You need to implement custom Encode Decoder depending on what you want to store and retrieve.

Another helpful link:
[How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)